# Why Add to cart not working for complete magento 2 website in Internet Explorer

Tags: magento2, addtocart, browser

> Here in our website Addtocart option not working in magento 2 for
>   Internet Explorer latest version also.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any console logs?

Comment: please check i added in question now.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open a websocket on a local (intranet) domain and IE is throwing a security error

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you will have to disable IE's automatic algorithm for recognising local sites.

You can find this in the settings: Tools > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites and un-tick all the boxes.